# Do extracted React Native components belong to me or client?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm

I develop mobile apps with React Native and have many components that are shared across projects, i.e., `<StandardTextInput />`, `<LargeHallowButton />`, and etc.

My clients and I have an agreement and they own any and all code worked on during this project. I would like to extract these shared components into a single npm module, owned by me but open-source, and then use it like any other component library. This would cut costs for both parties but would then make the client dependent on the maintenance of this module, i.e., me.

My question is whether or not doing the above would violate the agreement between me and my clients? If not, it is ethical to make their applications dependent on my library?

I had planned on speaking with them about this but wanted to consult the community first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally have done exactly the same thing. I manage a project called "react-native-pinch-new" which has been used in numerous projects for different clients including some major software companies.

However making those open source was beneficial for them in a way that they can easily use the same package for their other projects that develop internally. Because of that, my clients were happy with that and I had no legal issues. But this actually depends on your NDA terms and other contract terms you have already signed. So I think it is better to talk with your client first before publishing the code.

Comment: Thanks. Will speak with them.